# SEM (Structural Equation Modelling) with Exploratory Factor Analysis

Tags: data, structural-equation-modelling, exploratory-factor-analysis

Problem Statement: I need to do some Structural Equation Modelling at work to get the main factors in a marketing survey data-set.

1. There are no assumed equations to perform SEM on so what would be the best exploratory way to create those equations out of the data
2. All variables are very highly correlated across all the variables so how can we deal with that

Please let me know if I can help you with any supplements.

Comment: what is the outcome of exploratory factor analysis ? results!